# input only allow number 1-100 javascript

Tags: javascript, html, percentage

i want to make input percentage using javascript

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount" name="amount">
```

i made the js so when i input, it's adding %

```
var amount = document.getElementById('amount');
amount.addEventListener('input', function(e){
    amount.value = amount.value.replace('%','') + '%';
})
```

but it still can input character, i want to only allow number 1-100, is it possible?

or maybe you have suggestion about what is better to input for percentage

Comment: Try using [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) along with [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to achieve your desired outcome.

Comment: can you give me example of that?

Comment: There are examples in the links attached.

Comment: @AlghanyJagad whichever solution you use, be careful for the case where the User copy-pastes a value inside the input . You should cover that aswell + a validation before submitting the input value somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little late. This is an interesting example. One could incorporate some more logic here. The example below only allows numbers between 0 and 100 and adds the % at the end. Once you have entered a number up to max one, you have to start again. a new logic would have to be built in here.

```js
let amount = document.getElementById('amount');
amount.addEventListener('input', function(){
  const n = amount.value.replace('%','');
  if ( n >= 0 && n <= 100 ) {
    amount.value = amount.value.replace('%','') + '%'     
  } else {
     amount.value = n.slice(0, -1) + '%'  
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount" name="amount">
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML input `type` attribute allows `number` value so that it will only be able to accept number values.
And you can also pass a `max` attribute that will set a limit for entered number.
e.g.:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="amount" name="amount" max="[YOUR_NUMBER]">
```

Edit:
You can still validate your input with a JS function.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount" name="amount">
```

```js
let amount = document.getElementById('amount');
amount.addEventListener('input', function(e){
    amount.value = amount.value.replace('%','')
    let tmpValue = +amount.value
    amount.value = 0 <= tmpValue <= 100 ? tmpValue + '%' : "[VALUE IF NOT 1<AMOUNT<100]";
})
```

Comment: but using type number won't allow to add " % "  character

Comment: is there other option besides change the type? because i need the type still in text

Comment: @AlghanyJagad: can the unit be changed by the user, or will it only ever be in percentage? If it's *always* a percentage then make that clear outside of the `<input>`, if it *can* be changed then perhaps use a second element - perhaps `<select>` - to allow the user to make their choice? There are always alternatives, you just have to weigh up the pros and cons of those alternatives.

Comment: @MihaiT Why should it be part of the input anyway? This is the wrong way to use inputs. It's either should be a `range` or a `number` type.

Comment: @AlghanyJagad edited my answer,Try now.

Comment: @Sugar why a wrong way ? OP wants in a text input to have a string that can contain only digits and " %"  character. What is wrong with that ?

Comment: @ext i've tried it but it show NaN%, i've tried it in jsfiddle and it works, maybe there is something wrong in my code, thanks for your answer

Comment: @MihaiT because it makes validation way unnecessary complicated. `900%` `%%%%` `090%` become valid things. Also if it requires float numbers then case become even worse.

Comment: @AlghanyJagad your input is text and you try compare string with numbers. use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) on part of the string before comparing it to numbers

Comment: No validation is complicated when you use regexp :) Or, just  check for numbers only. Then check the range ( between 0 and 100 )  then add  % character when all the other conditions are met. Is not that complicated.